# Kivy Wxidgets are Sticking to Bottom of Window

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to have the buttons stay at the top like this,
[image]

However when I try to do it I get this,
[image]

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MainScreen(GridLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

#My Kv file:
<MainScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        size: root.width, 40
        cols: 3
    
        Button:
            text:"1"
        Button:
            text:"2"
        Button:
            text:"3"
```

I want the three columns as I have it I just can't find any way to get the whole thing to be at the top of the window.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Kivy, but I guess the problem is because of the nested GridLayout. MainScreen is a GridLayout, that contains an additional GridLayout in the layout file included in the example (Kv file). My guess is if this nesting is removed the buttons will display at the top.

Comment: I've tried using other methods that don't use a kv file and it still favors the bottom of the window. Every tutorial I've watched shows the buttons going to the top though so I just don't know what's happening,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the nested `GridLayouts` you can do:

```
<MainScreen>:
    cols: 1
    GridLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: root.width, 40
        cols: 3

        Button:
            text:"1"
        Button:
            text:"2"
        Button:
            text:"3"
```

or, if you do not want the nested `GridLayout`:

```
<MainScreen>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: 40
    pos_hint: {'top':1}
    cols: 3

    Button:
        text:"1"
    Button:
        text:"2"
    Button:
        text:"3"
```